# change scrollTop() in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

in bootstrap modal when i append new form at the bottom, i want to move my `scrollTop()` from its position, i.e. is probably `"0"`, to `100px`, when I click on the ajax Link it shows a form, after execution of the code shown the form I have put the code :

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 100 });
```

i think it should do its job as i wish but it does not. I have also put the code in the parent page as a function scrollDown(n) and call that function after form showing code in Ajax. but still no luck....
I don't know what i am doing wrong?

Any help be appreciated. thanks

EDIT: 
This code shows email form in the modal which actually change modal height and i want to move the scroll bar to apx: 100px down from top.
the code which shows form is:

```
function showEmailBox(person_sno,fir_sno,divFrm){
    try{
        $("#"+divFrm).show();
        $("#"+divFrm).removeClass("animated rubberBand");
        $("#"+divFrm).load("../ajaxPhp/emailReminderForm.php",{person_sno:person_sno,fir_sno:fir_sno,divFrm:divFrm},function(txt,status,xhr){
            if(xhr.statusText == 'OK'){
                $(this).html(txt).addClass("animated rubberBand");
                }
            else{
                $(this).html('Error: - '+ xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText).addClass('text-danger');
                }
            });             
        }catch(e){
            alert(e.message);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("animated rubberBand");
                },500);
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 100 });
        }
```

Here in the last line

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 100 });
```

this line does not work?

Comment: Can you create a snippet and explain what "exactly" that doesn't work? Your question is kinda unclear at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for same problem.
You can make `scrollTop` 0px for that,

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : '0px'}, 0);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Dear @Harshal Patil i have checked your code but still its not working, i think as i am doing this from bootstrap modal and there could be some issue with this? is it not?

Comment: @AbdulRahman I did this thing for bootstrap modal only. Make sure you add this script before showing modal. Try to add this script as soon as you enter into js function also .

Comment: Yes, i am not executing this code before showing modal... let me try

Comment: i am using jquery-1.8.3.min.js, the code does not working. but in fact i have the scenario where in open bootstrap modal i click on a link and it open new email form in that same modal meaning thereby that it is changing the height by adding form elements. So, i need to put the code which scroll down the scroll-bar from top to bottom. I think i have put the question wrong?

Comment: @AbdulRahman can you write down some function in js and then on button onclick do this this.

Comment: Yes its works fine but on the singe page not on tweeter bootstrap:) see the following post for reference...

Comment: @AbdulRahman refer this fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/patilharshal16/3kgbG/1284/